# Como carregar modal de edite dinamicamente usando Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Em uma aplicação estou fazendo o seguinte para carregar meus Modals Bootstrap

index.blade.php

obs: data-target(#edit{{$ecategory->id}}) usado para chamar os modal

```
@foreach($ecategories as $ecategory) //listando os registros
  <tr class="danger">
    <td>{{ $ecategory->name }}</td>
    <td> <a href="{{route('categories.edit', ['id'=>$ecategory->id])}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit{{$ecategory->id}}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" >Editar</a>
    <a href="{{route('categories.destroy', ['id'=>$ecategory->id])}}"  class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" >Excluir</a> </td>
  </tr>
    @endforeach

@foreach($ecategories as $ecategory) // listando os modals de cada registro
<div class="modal fade" id="edit{{$ecategory->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="categoryedit_title" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
  @endforeach
```

edit.blade.php

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
  <h4 id='categoryedit_title' class="modal-title">Editando Categoria</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  @include('errors._check')

  {!! Form::model($category, ['route'=>['categories.update', $category->id]])  !!}

  @include('categories._form')

  <div class="form-group" >

    {!! Form::submit('Atualizar Categoria', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
  </div>

  {!! Form::close()  !!}


  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>

  </div>
```

assim eu consegui abrir o modal de cada registro, mas ai o meu html fica cheio de modals

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="categoryedit_title" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="edit5" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="categoryedit_title" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="edit6" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="categoryedit_title" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="edit7" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="categoryedit_title" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="edit8" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="categoryedit_title" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

estou tentando gerar dinamicamente, mas não tive sucesso. alguém tem uma solução?

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema está ocorrendo aqui:

```
@foreach($ecategories as $ecategory) // listando os modals de cada registro
<div class="modal fade" id="edit{{$ecategory->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="categoryedit_title" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
  @endforeach
```

Como você está está fazendo um loop ele está criando vários modais ai quando você clica no botão para abrir o modal em especifico ele acaba acaba pegando a referência errada do modal.

Comment: Deste modo que estou fazendo está dando certo, não está pegando nenhuma informação errado, oque quero é tirar esse loop, e carregar o modal dinamicamente, mas aproveitar o edit.blade.php e a rota

Comment: Nesse caso você pode fazer um if no blade por exemplo:

@if(Rout::getCurrentRouteName() == "rotax")
 AQUI FICA O QUE TU QUER MOSTRAR
@endif

Comment: não entendi muito bom, mas está dando erro Undefined offset: 0

Comment: Outro exemplo: @if(Route::currentRouteName() == "lancamentos.index"  )
       @include('layout.header-with-blue-menu')
    @end

Outro exemplo, eu uso isso para modificar a estrutura estética dos menus

Comment: Isso não resolve no meu caso.